# How to bend a straight strip into a complete circle?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

i'm strying to bend this detailed ornamentation into a complete circle, like in this chandelier

[image]

[image]

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is to use the *Simple Deform* modifier in *Bend* mode on *Z* (make sure that you've applied the rotation of your object):

[image]

Another way is to use a *Curve* modifier with a circle as *Object*, but it won't be as quick as *Simple Deform*. Of course if the shape was not a circle it would be the best solution